# Remobe blank rows from select menu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have this list:

```
export enum UserRoleType {
  masterAdmin = 'ROLE_MASTER_ADMIN'
  merchantAdmin = 'ROLE_MERCHANT_ADMIN'
  resellerAdmin = 'ROLE_RESELLER_ADMIN'
}

export const AdminRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.masterAdmin]: 'Master Admin'
};

export const MerchantRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.merchantAdmin]: 'Merchant Admin'
};

export const ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = {
  [UserRoleType.resellerAdmin]: 'Reseller Admin'

};


public ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping = ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping;
  public roleTypes = Object.values(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

Dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="role">
        <option [value]="roleType" *ngFor="let roleType of roleTypes">{{ ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[roleType] }}</option>
        <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback" *ngIf="controlHasErrors('role')">
          {{controlValidateMessage('role')}}
        </div>
      </select>
```

I tried to use only the keys like this:

```
public roleTypes = Object.keys(UserRoleType).filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
```

But I get then only blank rows.

I want to display different const based on the type of the page. But for some reason I get select menu with several blank rows and the desired list. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 roleTypes = Object.keys(UserRoleType).filter(key => typeof UserRoleType[key] === 'string');
```

working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mg3hqy)
if you want the enum values in dropdown [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-35ixgv)
I see in dropdown you are loading options for ResellerRoleType2LabelMapping[role] which will match 1/3. So 2 will be blank option and one will have value like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1lvbr). is this what you want?

Comment: You can filter them out . filter( value => value != null) at the end